# Sophos UTM 9 Not Multicasting OSPF HELLO Messages

Tags: linux, networking, router, routing, firewall

I am attempting to enable OSPF on a Sophos UTM 9 on a LAN interface downstream from which are two other routers successfully running OSPF.

My configuration is as follows.

Interfaces and Routing --> Dynamic Routing (OSPF)

- Global

  - OSPF status: Toggled on (i.e. green)
  - Router ID: 192.168.30.1 (i.e. the IP address on the LAN1 interface)
- Area

  - Name: normal 0.0.0.0
  - Area-ID: 0.0.0.0
  - Area-type: Normal
  - Auth-type: Off
  - Connect via Interface: LAN1
- Interfaces

  - Name: LAN1
  - Interface: LAN1
  - Auth-type: Off
  - Cost: 0
  - Advanced

    - Hello interval: 10
    - Retransmit interval: 5
    - Dead interval: 40
    - Priority: 1
    - Transmit delay: 1
- Advanced

  - Redistribute connected <-- Checked
  - Metric: 10

Firewall configuration is as follows to allow OSPF's multicast messages:

Network Protection --> Firewall

- LAN1 ----- (OSPF) -----> Multicast

  - Enabled
- Multicast ----- (OSPF) -----> LAN1

  - Enabled

Here, OSPF is defined as a service definition with the following characteristics:

- Name: OSPF
- Type of definition: IP
- Protocol number: 89

Here, multicast is defined as a network definition with the following characteristics:

- 224.0.0.0/4
- Interface: Any

When I log into the Sophos UTM 9 as root and run tcpdump on the LAN1 interface, I see OSPFv2 "Hello" messages from the directly attached router being sent to multicast address 224.0.0.5, but I do not see the Sophos UTM 9 emitting any OSPF "Hello" messages.

One thing I've noticed... It seems that enabling OSPF on the interface in question does not subscribe that interface to the relevant OSPF multicast groups: 224.0.0.5 and 224.0.0.6

This shouldn't affect *outbound* multicast OSPF messages though (which, as stated, is where I am seeing the problem).

For *inbound* messages, as I indicated above, tcpdump shows they are hitting the NIC, but I doubt they are getting passed up the TCP/IP stack given the lack of a subscription.

```
my-utm:/root # ip maddr show eth0
2: eth0
link 33:33:00:00:00:01
link 33:33:00:00:00:02 users 2
link 01:00:5e:00:00:01
inet 224.0.0.1
inet6 ff05::2
inet6 ff01::2
inet6 ff02::2
inet6 ff02::1
inet6 ff01::1
```

From the configuration and observations described above, is anybody able to see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

EDITED TO ADD:
I've also noticed that, even though I explicitly have OSPF enabled, there's nothing in the process list that obviously sounds like a daemon to handle routing protocols. I'm not quite sure what I should expect to find here.

Comment: Does Sophos have a "networks" configuration for OSPF? It seems like it's frr/quagga-based, where OSPFv2 was always enabled for specific subnets, not for specific interfaces.

Comment: The configuration does seem to be interface-centric , rather than subnet-centric. The configuration options as presented in the web GUI are as I textually outlined above, with the exception that I omitted the configuration options under the "Message Digest" and "Debug" tabs. Nothing under those tabs seems relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: Can you write the answer as an answer & not an edit to the question; also remove 'solved' from the title. Self-answers are perfectly acceptable, & you can mark it as accepted, which will then identify it as 'solved'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was just a simple case of a missing check in a checkbox. I'd mistaken a check box for the "garbage can" icon one frequently sees in the UTM UI and which is used to delete an item.

In addition to defining an interface, one must also say on a per-area basis which interfaces are to be a part of that area (which makes sense).

Having done this, there is now an ospfd daemon running, the network interface is now subscribed to multicast groups 224.0.0.5 / 224.0.0.6, and routes are being exchanged.